# i have installed qt version 6.0.3 and this error QMYSQL driver not loaded displaying again and again

Tags: qt, cmake, mysql-connector, qsqldatabase

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt6" that is compatible
with requested version "6.6.3".

The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

```
C:/Qt/6.6.3/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake, version: 6.6.3 (64bit)
```

can any one help me out with this error??

I have try building plugins through qmake but i dont have mysql.pro file available at the location..
and also I have downloaded the mysql connector/c and mysql server 8.0.2

Comment: The part `(64bit)` means that you have QT installed for 64-bit platform, but your project (which uses QT) is configured for 32-bit platform. Either configure your project for 64-bit platform, or install QT for 32 platform.